# response.transmitfile changes the filename

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit1.Click

    Dim filename As String = "C:\pdfs\" + TextBox1.Text
    Response.TransmitFile(filename)

End Sub
```

Textbox1.text is the name of a pdf including extension.  THis works fine except the filename of the pdf gets changed to the name of the webpage that I call it from.  The name of the pdf in c:\pdfs remains as it was though.

Can i stop it changing the name.

Comment: You really should validate the filename before using it; at least append `.pdf` in the code. Someone could enter something like ..\Windows\somesystemfile in the textbox and, if the file permissions are not set correctly then someone could get the Windows password file or other information which should not be allowed to leak out. (A directory-traversal vulnerability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Response.TransmitFile to

```
Dim fileInfo As FileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\pdfs\" + TextBox1.Text)

 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", TextBox1.Text));
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
 Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
 Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can continue using Transferfile but in this way.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
```

//LINE1: Add the "**file name**" and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header and the name

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

//Add the file size into the response header

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
```

//Set the ContentType

```
response.ContentType = file.Extension.ToLower();
```

//Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)

```
response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
```

Comment: Thanks!  You set me on the right track.  However, ```response.ContentType = file.Extension.ToLower();``` doesn't feels right.  You should map the extension to the real Content-Type (ex.:  .pdf = application/pdf, .png = image/png, etc.).